# How to keep count in a recursive function in R?

Tags: r, recursion

I have a recursive function in R. I would like to track it and know how many times the function is called during the procedure. How can I do it in R?

EDIT: sample code:

```
test <- function(num)
{
  if(num>100)
    return(num)
  num <- num+4
  res <- test(num)
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: Rcpp is particularly well suited for recursion. R, really sucks at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach that does not require a global and `<<-` is:

```
test <- function(num, count=0) {
  if(num > 100)
    return(list(res=num, count=count))
  num <- num+4
  res <- test(num, count+1)
  return(res)
}
```

Note that the signature for invoking `test` is the same.

```
test(1)
##$res
##[1] 101
##
##$count
##[1] 25
```

Answer (score 7):

create a global variable using the `<<-` operator then index it in the recursive function.

```
counter <<- 0
```

then in your function that will be used recursively simply:

```
counter <<- counter +1
```

Comment: Assigning to a variable in global scope is not great practice, though. This will also break if the function customizes its scope.

Comment: yes, agreed. @aichao gives a more elegant solution. Global side effects are, as a rule, a really bad idea.